# 404 error while checking for update

Tags: updates, update-manager

I tried to check for updates in mu ubuntu 14.04 and getting error

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jconti/gnome3/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those ppas do not exist

They are not official Ubuntu ppa and you must have manually added them.

To remove them:

Open Update manager, select settings and remove them from  the "Other Software" tab in "Software Sources".

[image]

Comment: Thanks Warren it worked. Now I am not getting the error.